Can other Chrome extensions use my Firebase Auth or Google Sign in and if so, how do I prevent that?
I am working on a Chrome extension that needs to login through Firebase Authentication or Google Sign-in. I am considering to just have my own website https://example.com/login-chrome-extension to deal with the login flow and my extension with the permission to my own website https://example.com can read the token and proceed to use the APIs.
This made me think, what prevents other people from just using someone else's Firebase Authentication? For example, if you have an app at https://your-example-app.com/login with all the public Firebase information, in my own Chrome extension, I can just get host permission to https://your-example-app.com and grab the sign-in token through script injection. Basically I am "piggybacking" your authentication system and leaving you to deal with increased MAU.
I simply need to authenticate a verified user, so as soon as I can grab an ID token, I can always verify it on my server with Google's public JWKs and certificates. At first I thought you can't publish your Chrome extension publicly since you are using someone else's domain but this is not the case. There are tons of extensions that legitimately have permission to other domains they don't own.
Is this really a concern? How is it prevented?
// User click Login: launch https://your-example-app.com/login

// Script injected into https://your-example-app.com/login
const idToken = await loginWithFirebase(); // This should be valid with all the public info exposed
sendTokenToBackground(idToken); // Using message passing or redirect it to chrome-extension://id/token-return.html?token=token

// In the background or the token-return page, use the token as I please knowing the user is a verified Google user.

